# Can I control a unity standalone app from a web browser?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, mapping

I'm starting a project to control my Unity Standalone App for Windows from a web browser. The App is a video projection over a physical object (videomapping), so i do not have to see any text over the projection. The control panel to change objects is located on the web browser. Any ideas?

I check the protocol to modify registry https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85) but this is helpful just to open the App, the important task is to pass simple variables to the Standalone App like show or hide objects.

I don't do it all in webgl because I need to make some complex camera vertex distortions and webgl is consuming too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your App from anywhere, you could write a simple webserver to fit your needs.

The webserver has a simple website that serves as your Control UI.

You can connect your Unity Standalone App to the Webserver (i.e. HTTP) to get your input.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll check around your suggestion.